# How to make automatic type inference with adding totals & sorting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a variable with the following data:

```
var data = [
    {date: "2007-04-23", a: "93.24", b: "10.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-24", a: "95.35", b: "20.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-25", a: "98.84", b: "30.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-26", a: "99.92", b: "40.24"}
    ];
```

I need to do the following steps:

- make automatic type inference in order to add a+b because it’s string now
- add column “total “ with the sum of a+b
- sort rows by “total” from greatest to least

The result should be:

```
var data = [
{date: "2007-04-26", a: 99.92, b: 40.24, total:140.16},
{date: "2007-04-24", a: 95.35, b: 20.24, total:115.59},
{date: "2007-04-23", a: 93.24, b: 20.24, total:113.48},
{date: "2007-04-25", a: 98.84, b: 10.24, total:109.08}
    ];
```

I know you can do it when parsing csv file.
I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
  
    <body>
   
        <script>
    var data = [
    {date: "2007-04-23", a: "93.24", b: "20.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-24", a: "95.35", b: "20.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-25", a: "98.84", b: "10.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-26", a: "99.92", b: "40.24"}

    ];
  data.columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
var data1 = autoType(data),
(d, i, columns) => (d3.autoType(d), d.total = d3.sum(columns, c => d[c]), d).sort((a, b) => b.total - a.total);

      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this with the defined variable?

Answer (score 2):

You could map a new array with totals and sort by `total`.

```js
const
    data = [{ date: "2007-04-23", a: "93.24", b: "10.24" }, { date: "2007-04-24", a: "95.35", b: "20.24" }, { date: "2007-04-25", a: "98.84", b: "30.24" }, { date: "2007-04-26", a: "99.92", b: "40.24" }],
    result = data
        .map(({ a, b, ...o }) => ({ ...o, a: +a, b: +b, total: +(+a + +b).toFixed(2) }))
        .sort((a, b) => b.total - a.total);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It sums and sorts...but how can i make automatic type inference in order to delete quotation marks for "a" and "b" columns?

Comment: do you want numbers in the result? you need to convert the values to number.

Comment: Yes, I need numbers. BTW do you knowe why there is 14 numbers after the decimal poin in some total numbers? How can I cut down to 2 numbers.

Comment: that is a problem of [floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1447675), where die values are not exactly matching in decimal system, because of storing bitwise with a short range. to overcome this to get the wanted digits, you could convert to string with two decimals and get a number of the string (or keep the string).

Answer (score 2):

[`d3.autoType`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#autoType) was created to be used when fetching/parsing a DSV, but you can easily use it in your case, passing the objects in your array. For instance (use your browser console to see real date objects):

```js
var data = [
    {date: "2007-04-23", a: "93.24", b: "10.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-24", a: "95.35", b: "20.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-25", a: "98.84", b: "30.24"},
    {date: "2007-04-26", a: "99.92", b: "40.24"}
];
    
var converted = data.map(row => d3.autoType(row));

console.log(converted)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to add total column with d3.sum ?